# Incorrect historgram when grouped in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Generate some data

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000)+3),
                  y=as.factor(c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",1000))))
```

Plot historgram (incorrect)

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x,fill=y)) +
   geom_histogram(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]
Correct version

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x))+ 
   geom_histogram(data=subset(dat,y=='A'),aes(fill=y),alpha=0.5)+
   geom_histogram(data=subset(dat,y=='B'),aes(fill=y),alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: It looks like in incorrect version you have one histogram (with two colors) and in correct one you actually have two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `position` parameter:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x,fill=y)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.5, position = 'identity')
```

Answer (score -1):

The aim of ggplot is to make both datasets fully visible. Parameter alpha enables to do it using transparency. A lack of transparency shows both datasets one atop the second one, what suggests incorrect shape.

Comment: The alpha parameter is defined in the first example, so this is not the cause of the observed behaviour.

Comment: OK, I was concentrated on the explanation, that "incorrect" histogram is not incorrect, but presented in another style.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. I mentally replace "incorrect" with "undesired" when reading SO questions, because that's usually what the poster means.